# Callback C++ Class method from C

Tags: c++, c, callback

I am trying to callback C++ class methods from C. Now I have got something working, but am not sure if this is the best solution.

I am looking for feedback, as to if there is something wrong with this approach, and how could I make this better.

So, here goes my code:

This is the C++ class `Foo`. The class has the methods `getValue()` & `setValue()`, which I would like to like to be called-back from the C code:

Contents of `Foo.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    int getValue() const;
    void setValue(int value);

private:
    int value_;
};
#endif

// Free functions
int  c_wrapper_getValue(void *arg1);
void c_wrapper_setValue(int value, void *arg1);
```

Contents of the source file, `Foo.cpp`:

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo() :
    value_{0}
{}

int Foo::getValue() const
{
    return value_;
}

void Foo::setValue(int value)
{
    value_ = value;
}

void c_wrapper_setValue(int value, void *arg1)
{
    Foo* foo_instance = static_cast<Foo*>(arg1);
    foo_instance->setValue(value);
}

int c_wrapper_getValue(void *arg1)
{
    Foo* foo_instance = static_cast<Foo*>(arg1);
    return foo_instance->getValue();
}
```

Here is the code for the C files, which in turn call the `Foo` class members. First, the header `Test.h` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Foo.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Callback function pointers
typedef int  (*get_handler_t)(void* arg1);
typedef void (*set_handler_t)(int foo, void* arg1);

void register_handler(get_handler_t g, set_handler_t s, void* p_instance);

// These are the functions which call the callback functions
int call_cpp_get_function();
void call_cpp_set_function(int value);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And finally the `Test.c` file:

```
#include "Test.h"

static get_handler_t get_handler_ = NULL;   /**< Getter function pointer of type int (*g)(void *). */
static set_handler_t set_handler_ = NULL;   /**< Setter function pointer of type void (*s)(int,  void *). */
static void* foo_object_instance  = NULL;    /**< Instance of Foo object. */

//! Registers the getter and setter function with the object of Class Foo
//! \param g Getter function pointer of type int (*g)(void *).
//! \param s Setter function pointer of type void (*s)(int,  void *).
//! \param p_instance Instance of Foo object.
void register_handler(
    int (*g)(void *),
    void (*s)(int,  void *),
    void* p_instance)
{
    get_handler_ = g;
    set_handler_ = s;
    foo_object_instance = p_instance;
}

//! Function calls the get function of class Foo
//! \return Value of value_ from class Foo
int call_cpp_get_function()
{
    return get_handler_(foo_object_instance);
}

//! Function calls the set function of class Foo
//! \param value Value to be set in class Foo
void call_cpp_set_function(int value)
{
    set_handler_(value, foo_object_instance);
}
```

Now I could create an object and call the functions present in my C file, which called back the C++ methods, like this:

```
Foo foo_object;
register_handler(&c_wrapper_getValue, &c_wrapper_setValue, static_cast<void *>(&foo_object));
call_cpp_get_function();
call_cpp_set_function(35);
```

I do have some constraints in my case, for example I can't use STL, since the code is supposed to run on an embedded system. So, how bad is my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Encapsulate stuff that shouldn't be `public`

I'd rather make the callback functions private static functions of the c++ class This helps to encapsulate the nasty `void*`casts:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    int getValue() const;
    void setValue(int value);

    void register_callbacks();

private:
    int value_;

    static int  cb_getValue(void *arg1);
    static void cb_wrapper_setValue(int value, void *arg1);
};
#endif
```

Implementation:

```
void Foo::register_callbacks() {
    register_handler(Foo::cb_getValue, Foo::cb_setValue, static_cast<void *>(this));
}

void Foo::cb_setValue(int value, void *arg1) {
    Foo* foo_instance = static_cast<Foo*>(arg1);
    foo_instance->setValue(value);
}

int Foo::cb_getValue(void *arg1) {
    Foo* foo_instance = static_cast<Foo*>(arg1);
    return foo_instance->getValue();
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo foo_object;
foo_object.register_callbacks();
call_cpp_get_function();
call_cpp_set_function(35);
```